# Code for multiple ranges of increasing numbers to determine representative number

Tags: r, range, distribution, probability

I seek guidance on R code to make a probability calculation based on survey data.  The survey asked respondents to select from five descriptions of how often they sought advice (the “frequency” variable in the data frame below).  The number of respondents choosing each description is the “respondent” variable and the maximum I have assumed for each frequency is in the “max.year.est” variable.

```
use <- data.frame(frequency = c("rarely; less than once per quarter",
                                "very occasionally; about every other month",
                                "occasionally; about once per month", 
                                "fairly frequently; more than once per month",
                                "very frequently; once a week or more"),
                  respondents = c(50, 40, 30, 20, 10),
                  max.year.est = c(3, 6, 12, 18, 78))
```

The `dplyr` call mutates three columns to the use data frame that each present an annual total of requests for advice by the respondent group after multiplying the respondents (i) by a maximum number for each range -- which makes assumptions about the top of a range in the two most frequent; (ii) by the mid-point of max.requests for a more reasonable intermediate assumption; and (iii) by 40% of mean.requests, a figure pulled out of a hat because it seems reasonable that lower numbers of requests will be more common in each range than higher numbers.

```
use %>% group_by(frequency) %>% 
  mutate(max.requests = respondents * max.year.est) %>%
  mutate(mean.requests = 0.5*max.requests) %>%
  mutate(lower.requests = 0.4*max.requests)
```

If we assume the annual requests for advice in each range are distributed in a reasonable pattern, with more respondents making requests at smaller numbers in a range and fewer as you move up the range, what is a statistical method and R code (Poisson distribution?) to arrive at a defensible number of total annual requests in each range given the assumptions above?

Thank you for your comments and answers.

Comment: This is a Stats question, not a coding question.  I suggests asking this on Cross Validated  (http://stats.stackexchange.com )

Comment: Thanks.  I have just posted on Stats.  Should I delete this question here?

Comment: Probably a good idea, but not required...